# How to hard code login credentials in OAuth 2.0 for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am using oauth 2.0 for the SoundCloud SDK and I just want recordings that the user of my iOS app makes to be uploaded to my account on soundcloud. Is there a way I can hard code my username and password? I don't want to make a sign in screen where the user has to sign in. I searched around for this but I can't find anything since OAuth 2.0 allows users to authorize the application without disclosing their username and password. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should never be done in the app for a number of reasons. For example, what happens when you want or need to change your password? Now you have to submit a new version to the App Store and hope that all your users upgrade.

My suggestion would be to move all your soundcloud upload calls to a server side solution and keep your credentials there

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough solution that goes against encapsulation, so it probably isn't the best way, but I also couldn't find any specific documentation.

In your AppDelegate, import "NXOAuth2AccountStore.h" and "SCConstants.h" in addition to "SCSoundCloud.h"

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
requestAccessToAccountWithType:kSCAccountType
username:@"yourUsername"
password:@"yourPassword"];
```

Implement the getTracks method as shown in the SoundCloud iOS SDK documentation, but handle the jsonResponse as follows:

```
    if (!jsonError && [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        self.tracksArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:jsonResponse, nil];
        NSLog(@"json response is %@", jsonResponse);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

In the tableView methods, I was getting exception errors pulling info from the self.tracksArray property as it was shown. This was probably accounted for in the original handler that used the loginViewController. You can fix it by calling firstObject on self.tracksArray. I'm sure there is a better way though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSMutableString`s to build your username and password at runtime, that way they aren't visible in the App binary file. Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *password;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupCreds];
    return YES;
}

- (void)setupCreds
{
    self.username = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [self.username appendString:@"u"];
    [self.username appendString:@"s"];
    [self.username appendString:@"e"];
    [self.username appendString:@"r"];

    self.password = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [self.password appendString:@"p"];
    [self.password appendString:@"w"];
    [self.password appendString:@"d"];
}
```